Find residues of $f(z)=1/(1+z^3)$
I am doing an exercise where it asks to find the branch residues of $$f(z)=\frac{1}{1+z^3}$$
I already found the poles: $z=-1$ and $z=e^{\pm\frac{i\pi}{3}}$, but I do not know how to find the pole order and thus compute the residues. (For the integral i have to compute I only need the Residue at $z=e^{-\frac{i\pi}{3}}$)
I tried to put $f$ as a laurent series that shows $(z-e^{-\frac{i\pi}{3}})^n$ but i cannot find how.

It is a simple pole because there are three distinct cube roots of $-1$. If $z_0$ is a simple pole of $f$ then residue at $z_0$ is $\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z)$. In this case, the limit is $\frac1 {3z_0^{2}}$.

$$f(z)=\frac{1/3}{z+1}+\frac{e^{2i\pi/3}/3}{z+e^{2i\pi/3}}+\frac{e^{-2i\pi/3}/3}{z+e^{-2i\pi/3}}.$$

One way to expand in powers of $z-e^{-i\pi/3}$ is to substitute $w=z-e^{-i\pi/3}$ and then expand in powers of $w$.

$$
\begin{align}
w&=z-e^{-i\pi/3}\\
z&=w+e^{-i\pi/3}\\
z^3 &= w^3+\left(\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)w^2+
\left(-\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)w-1
\\
1+z^3 &= w^3+\left(\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)w^2+
\left(-\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)w
\\
\frac{1}{1+z^3} &= \frac{1}{\left(-\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}
\;\frac{1}{w}+O(1)
\\
\text{residue} &= \frac{1}{\left(-\frac{3}{2}+i\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)}
=-\frac{1}{6} - i \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}
\end{align}
$$

It seems I have a wrong sign in my answer.  Can you find the error?
